# Why text-to-image generation tends to be poor when prompting mythological figures?

Tags: image-generation, text-to-image

They only properly generate Greek mythological figures, failing to properly recognize figures from other mythologies. Is this caused due to the training data?

I have tried Dall-E and Stable Diffusion

Prompting a well known Greek mythological figure produces accurate images, but not for lesser known deities/creatures. For other mythologies they tend to generate images depicting specific versions of such characters, like Norse gods are depicted as Marvel's versions.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you're talking about from start to finish? (That is, what image generator, what prompts, what images you get as a result, and what problems you see with those images if it's not immediately obvious to the eye.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to draw something, a text-to-image model needs a consistent idea of what it looks like.  For something like "Zeus", society has converged on a single common vision, so that if you ask someone to draw Zeus, the result won't be too different from the [*Jupiter of Smyrna*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jupiter_Smyrna_Louvre_Ma13.jpg).

There's no such consensus for someone like the Babylonian [Enlil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlil).  If you train a model on a number of wildly different images with the same label, you'll be lucky if you get anything coherent out of it.  See, for example, the well-known inability of models to produce realistic hands.

In the specific case of the Norse gods, the vast majority of the images in the training data come from the Marvel pantheon, and are generally not labeled as such.  These overwhelm any other depictions, and make it difficult if not impossible to generate a non-Marvel version.